# Grandma's cipher

Tags: cipher

My Grandma sent me a text recently, even though she struggles to type what she means accurately (she accidently taps the keys more times than she needs to):

$\hskip2in$[image]

She used to be a code-breaker back in WW2, so she's always enciphering things, I suspect she may be sending me a code of some kind to crack...

What should I send back to her?

*Transcription:*

```
Hi Melkor!
Just got my new mobile & it's gr8!
Could you help me find what computer i should get?

or-sw-so-px-ve-te-uk-ud
```

---

*(Not part of the puzzle)*

I have tried to make this cipher as original as I can, so have fun and good luck! Brute-forcing this cipher **will not work**, this is a new cipher idea, and the clues in the puzzle will help you understand it.

*Hint:*

Grandma's new phone looks like this

> [image]

Comment: Does Cb refers to her name here, also please mention what war are you referring to?

Comment: Cb stands for code breaker, which I have already stated in the clue. As for the war, it was WW2.

Comment: >! Looks like it's a playfair cipher (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair_cipher).
>! The key is figuring out what the key should be.
>! I tried "grandma melkor" but got garbage.

Comment: @bill kidder no the cipher is more creative, you will not need to brute force it.

Comment: My memory is failing so I may be wrong, but I didn't think my old Nokia phone was able to send text messages.  (Maybe it's just that I didn't know anyone else with a phone which could receive text messages, so I just used the phone as a phone.)  Just googled - it did handle SMS - must have just been me not knowing anyone to send a message to.

Comment: You've made me nostalgic - I may have to hunt around the house and see if I can find it - I probably haven't thrown it out.

Comment: @YowE3K good luck finding it!

Comment: Can't be TOO hard to find - it's fairly large!! (But still only about 1/2 the height, width and depth of my first mobile phone.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word is

> COLOSSUS - a set of computers developed by British codebreakers in 1943-1945.
>
>  [image]

since she

> taps the keys more times than she ought to, the number sequence arising from the Nokia key matrix is $67, 79, 76, 79, 83, 83, 85, 83$ and this represents in ASCII COLOSSUS.

Comment: Well Done solving!